# C# How to copy a file without changing the original file name

Tags: c#, file-copying

I have this code:

```
var GetDLLFilesForDir = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dll"));
foreach (string DLLFilesForDir in GetDLLFilesForDir)
{
    File.Copy(DLLFilesForDir, Path.Combine(SADIR, DLLFilesForDir), true);
}
```

But as you can see, when I go to copy it I get an error.
I know the error is caused by "DLLFilesForDir", because it is trying to combine a path using "DLLFilesForDir" when I am already using that file.

The problem is, I need the file name to stay the same, so if I changed:

```
Path.Combine(SADIR, DLLFilesForDir);
```

To this:

```
Path.Combine(SADIR, DLLFilesForDir + "1");
```

Would it change the name of the file being copied because then I'd have a "filename1.dll" instead of "filename.dll" and I need the latter.

Help appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Can you be more clear. Why is the copy failing? Because the DLL is already loaded in a process? If so then you just need to make sure that everything that has it loaded, unloads it first.

Comment: Is the problem that the destination directory doesn't exist?  Try Debug.WriteLine(Path.Combine(SADIR, DLLFilesForDir)) to see what the destination is.

Comment: The error I get is: The process cannot access the file "filename.dll' because it is being used by another process, it is not being used by any other process but my own program.

Comment: Probably you'll get your answer here, but in the future you can debug such problem with the debugger in a minute yourself. Make yourself familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your

```
File.Copy(DLLFilesForDir, Path.Combine(SADIR, DLLFilesForDir), true);
```

to

```
File.Copy(DLLFilesForDir, Path.Combine(SADIR, Path.GetFileName(DLLFilesForDir)), true);
```

From the [MSDN page for Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2.

So you are trying the copy the file onto itself ^^

Comment: I'm trying to copy a file into a directory\folder, weather it exists or not it doesn't matter because it would overwrite.

Comment: Your `Path.Combine(SADIR, DLLFilesForDir)` returns `DLLFilesForDir` because that is an absolute path. So you get `File.Copy(DLLFilesForDir, DLLFilesForDir, true);` which doesn't work. Try the change I suggested.